# Enum type 'Enum' has members with initializers that are not literals

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to use an Enum value as literal type as shown below. However, I get the following error: `Enum type 'Enum' has members with initializers that are not literals.`

```
declare const enum Enum {
    A,
    B
}

interface Test {
    prop: Enum.A;
}
```

This works if I do the following though:

```
declare const enum Enum {
    A=0,
    B=1
}

interface Test {
    prop: Enum.A;
}
```

Why does this fix the problem? Doesn't using `const enum` set the values of the different enums to 0,1,2, etc.?

Note: This code is inside a `.d.ts` file

Comment: I think you need to remove the `declare` keyword, maybe?

Comment: I guess I should mention I'm doing this within a .d.ts file. If I do it in a .ts file and remove declare it works.

Comment: Ahhh, okay.  That makes sense, then.  (For inline code, you can use a single backtick)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TypeScript knows for sure that things are `0,1,2` for actual enums e.g.

```
const enum Enum {
    A
}

interface Test {
    prop: Enum.A;
}
```

This is because it has `A = 0` in its compilation context. However for a declaration

```
declare const enum Enum {
    A
}

interface Test {
    prop: Enum.A; // ERROR
}
```

It is out of its control and so it can't be *sure* without looking at the implementation *or* you providing it the hint it needs:

```
declare const enum Enum {
    A = 0
}

interface Test {
    prop: Enum.A; // OKAY
}
```